# Google Blogger API : AccessTokenRefreshError:invalid_grand message

Tags: python, blogger, google-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am using google-python-client-api for Blogger API (Service Account - OAuth).

This is my code (which is taken my tasks api [example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py))

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

f = file("privatekey.p12", "rb")
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    "2-abcdr@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    key,
    scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger")

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("blogger", "v3", http=http)
```

when I am running this code, its showing

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    D:\Code\myScripts\py\gData.py   20      
    build   build\bdist.win32\egg\apiclient\discovery.py    191     
    new_request build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py    402     
    _refresh    build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py    569     
    _do_refresh_request build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py    625     
AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

What's the problem and how should I fix it??

I even tried `tasks.py` example code.. and its even showing the same error

*I am very much sure that service account email address is right*

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into a similar problem with querying BigQuery. From what little documentation exists on the interwebs, it appears to be an issue with poor resolution clocks causing timing errors that invalidate the SignedJWTCredentials. One proposed solution is to ensure that your clock's timer is synchronized with ntp. Since I'm deploying to Heroku, my solution is to fail gracefully and then retry.

See also https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Solving_invalid_grant_errors